# How to sum only records with zero differences

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem in sql server query 
here is

```
Table 1
Id  |User   |Start  |End
====+=======+=======+======
1   | 5     | 1:00  | 2:00
2   | 5     | 2:00  | 3:00
3   | 5     | 3:00  | 4:00
4   | 5     | 7:20  | 8:35
5   | 7     | 3:00  | 4:30

Result 
ID  |User   |Start  |End    |TotalAll   |Running
====+=======+=======+=======+===========+========
1   |5      |1:00   | 2:00  | 3.0       | 1.0
2   |5      |2:00   | 3:00  | 3.0       | 2.0
3   |5      |3:00   | 4:00  | 3.0       | 3.0
4   |5      |7:20   | 8:35  | 1.25      | 1.25
5   |7      |3:00   | 4:30  | 1.5       | 1.5
```

Since session 1 & 2 & 3 are connected between each other time, without any break, and they're also from the same user, I want to have 2 additional columns, 
1, the totalHours of that connected sessions which is 3.0 hours, 
2, the running total, which for the first record it will be 1 hour, for the second it will be 2 hours, and the third it will be 3 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is to identify the which are the `"connected"` `Id`. For this, the recursive cte `rcte` query is used to identify based on `Start` and `End` time

As for `TotalAll` and `Running`, this is just using `sum()` with window function

```
; with 
cte as
(
    select  *, 
            rn  = row_number() over (partition by [User] order by [Start])
    from    your_table t
),
rcte as
(
    select  *, grp = 1
    from    cte 
    where   rn  = 1

    union all

    select  c.*, 
            grp = case when r.[End] = c.[Start] then r.grp else r.grp + 1 end
    from    rcte r
            inner join cte c    on  r.[User]    = c.[User]
                               and  r.rn        = c.rn - 1
)
select  r.[Id], r.[User], r.[Start], r.[End],
        TotalAll = sum(datediff(minute, [Start], [End])) 
                   over (partition by [User], [grp]) / 60.0,
        Running  = sum(datediff(minute, [Start], [End])) 
                   over (partition by [User], [grp] 
                             order by Id) / 60.0
from    rcte r
order by [Id]
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach, without recursion. You need to use windowed functions to define groups and calculate total and running hours:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    [Id] int,
    [User] int,
    [Start] time(0),
    [End] time(0)
)
INSERT INTO Data
    ([Id], [User], [Start], [End])
VALUES
    (1, 5, '01:00', '02:00'),
    (2, 5, '02:00', '03:00'),
    (3, 5, '03:00', '04:00'),
    (4, 5, '07:20', '08:35'),
    (5, 7, '03:00', '04:30')
```

Statment:

```
;WITH ChangesCTE AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN [Start] = LAG([End]) OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Id]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ChangeId
    FROM Data
), GroupsCTE AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(ChangeId) OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) AS GroupID
    FROM ChangesCTE
)
SELECT 
    [Id], [User], [Start], [End],
    DATEDIFF(minute, MIN([Start]) OVER (PARTITION BY [User], [GroupID]), MAX([End]) OVER (PARTITION BY [User], [GroupID])) / 60.0 AS Total,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, [Start], [End])) OVER (PARTITION BY [User], [GroupID] ORDER BY [Id]) / 60.0 AS Running
FROM GroupsCTE
```

Result:

```
Id  User    Start       End         Total       Running
1   5       01:00:00    02:00:00    3.000000    1.000000
2   5       02:00:00    03:00:00    3.000000    2.000000
3   5       03:00:00    04:00:00    3.000000    3.000000
4   5       07:20:00    08:35:00    1.250000    1.250000
5   7       03:00:00    04:30:00    1.500000    1.500000
```